# Spring Boot: "Failed to determine a suitable driver class" error with PostgreSQL in a Dockerized multi-module Gradle project

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a multi-module Gradle project with Spring Boot that consists of a shared module and a *spring-module-1*. I'm using *PostgreSQL* as my database, and I've set up *Docker* containers for the database and my Spring Boot application.

However, when I try to run my Spring Boot application container, I encounter the following error:

```
java_app  | 20:23:04.141 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Here's my Docker Compose configuration for reference:

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  # db name used to connect to the database via pgadmin
  java_db:
    container_name: java_db
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  spring-module-1:
    container_name: java_app
    environment: # environment variables to be used by the spring-module-1 container
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://java_db:5432/postgres
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - java_db # spring-module-1 depends on java_db and will wait for it to be ready before starting
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: spring-module-1:latest # name of the spring-module-1 image to be used
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # expose port 8080 of the container to port 8080 of the host machine

volumes:
  pgdata: { }
```

My build.gradle file for spring-module-1:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.springmodule1.SpringModule1Application'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '3.1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '3.1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.6.0'
    implementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.10.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.1.3')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
// create a single Jar with all dependencies
tasks.register('fatJar', Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.springmodule1.SpringModule1Application'
    }
    archiveBaseName = "${rootProject.name}"
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

My application.yaml file for spring-module-1:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    url: ${DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
```

Environment:

Docker version: 24.0.6, build ed223bc
Spring Boot version: 3.1.3
PostgreSQL version: 42.0.6

The full project code can be found in this Github repository: https://github.com/KosenkoA/multiproject

How I ran this code:

- Built fatJar locally, using the Gradle task "fatJar" (can be found in build.gradle file).
- Run the `docker compose build` command.
- Run the `docker compose up spring-module-1`, in the directory with the docker compose file.

What I did:

- I tried replacing the values of ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}, ${DATABASE_URL} and ${DATABASE_USERNAME} with the values defined in docker-compose.yml.
- Tried to use previous versions of postgresql dependencies. Used versions 42.5.1 and 42.4.3.

To no avail.

I expected to see the application and Postgres database running successfully inside Docker.

Comment: Remove your `fatJar` and `jar` and configuration for `bootJar` task and let Spring Boot build the executable jar. You are trying to outsmart the Spring Boot plugin which already creates a runnable jar with all the dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the help. 
Now it says:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class .
Despite l parameter being configured in application.yml file: 
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://java_db:5432/postgres
    password: postgres
    username: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: ...

Comment: Is your `application.yaml` in the correct location? If you want to override from docker just set `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as an environment paramter which will override the value from the `application.[properties|yaml]` file.

Comment: Just added SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL env variable and now error is: "Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata". 
It looks like the application.yml file is really not where it should be. However, when running the application outside the container, this problem does not occur. 

Do you have any idea where application.yml goes and how to build a jar with application.yml in the required location? (the project code can be found here: https://github.com/KosenkoA/multiproject).

Comment: If you place the `application.yml` in `src/main/resources` it will be used. So if it isn't there place it there. You didn't do as I explained, you are still trying to outsmart Spring Boot. Remove the `bootJar` task. Spring Boot already makes a runnable jar, you are interfering with that. Don't do that.